# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname'). How can I solve this issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I'm using all latest version and styled components, This is my App.js file

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
    
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GlobalStyle/>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<Hero />} />
          <Route path="/projects" exact element={<Projects />} />
          <Route path="/about" exact element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Navbar.js

```
 {menuData.map((item, index) => {
              const border = index === menuData.length-1 ? '1px solid #fff':'none';
              const padding = index === menuData.length-1 ? '0 24px':'0';
              
              return (
                <NavItem key={index}>
                  <NavLinks to={item.link} style={{border, padding}}>
                    {item.title}
                  </NavLinks>
                </NavItem>
              )
            })}
```

Comment: Is there a code stacktrace to go along with that error that tells you where the issue is in the code? I suspect you've a `Link` component missing a `to` prop. Can you include the stacktrace and all relevant as part of a [mcve]?

Comment: Yeah, looks like an issue with a link component. Can you share that code? Looks like the `NavItem` and `NavLinks` components we need to see. And please also share code and error messages as properly formatted and readable code/text snippets instead of images. Images are less accessible, aren't copy/pasteable, and can be more difficult for some to read.

Comment: I added the Navbar code to my post. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, can you share the component code that is trying to render the `react-router-dom` `Link` component?